# Kafka consumer offset lag even when auto commit is enabled

Tags: kafka-consumer-api

I am using Kafka 0.9 consumer APIs to consume some already published messages for a topic. I am using following code to continuously poll the messages from the broker for the specified topic. I am using `consumer.seek(topic, offset)` to begin reading the messages starting from offset 11700 and I receive all the messages beginning that offset as expected. However, when I look at the offset using kafka-consumer-offset-checker.sh, I always see same last committed offset (12700) and lag (1000) using following command.

```
bin/kafka-consumer-offset-checker.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic cardiac-dicom-message --group test7
```

Output:

```
Group           Topic                          Pid Offset          logSize         Lag             Owner

test7           cardiac-dicom-message          0   12700           13700           1000            none
```

Based on the Spark documentation, if we are doing polling in a loop, the call to `consumer.poll()` will commit the largest offset (13699) returned from previous `consumer.poll()` call so I am very confused.

Below is the example code:

```java
 Properties props = new Properties();
 props.put("bootstrap.servers", "kafka-server:9092");
 props.put("group.id", "test7");
 props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
 props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "10");
 props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
 props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
 props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
 KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);

 //consume specific partition
 TopicPartition topicPartion = new TopicPartition("cardiac-dicom-message", 0);
 consumer.assign(Arrays.asList(topicPartion));
 consumer.seek(topicPartion, 11700);

 while (true) {
     ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(1000);
     System.out.println("number of messages = " + records.count());
     int count=0;
     for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
         count++;
             System.out.printf("partition = %d, offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s\n", record.partition(), record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
     }
 }
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Do I understand your question correctly, ie, you receive all 2000 messages from 11700 to 13700, but only the "last commit" is not done?

Comment: Yes, I receive the all 2000 messages when I use consumer.seek(topic, offset) to begin reading the messages starting from offset 11700 but committed offset for this topic shows 12700.

Comment: Hmmm... No idea so far... Can you post the stdout output of your sample code?

Comment: Thanks but I am not able to reproduce this behavior again. Will come back with more info if I ever see the same issue.

Comment: If problem is gone, please delete this question to keep SO clean (you can reopen questions again any time later).